# MySQL query to select multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN (company_users) ON users.user_id=company_users.C_C_OWNER WHERE company_users.C_C_OWNER='19'
```

I get the following:
[image]

What I need to do is use the C_USER_ID field to select users in the user_id field under the users table. So far every way I try I get blank results. For example, there is a user 22 I want to grab.

Comment: please post text table data instead of images

Comment: How do you post a text table data?

Comment: copy paste into excel/notepad whatever - heres [a tool that'll format pretty print it](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: So just join a second time back to `users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users LEFT JOIN (company_users) 
ON users.user_id=company_users.C_USER_ID 
WHERE company_users.C_C_OWNER='19'
```

Guess my coffee did not kick in yet. I just needed to change where my select query was pointing.

Comment: Note that this will render as an INNER JOIN. Maybe you need another caffeine shot.

Comment: What is an INNER JOIN @Strawberry? Is that good or bad? Still learning MySQL syntax and DBA.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM users ,company_users
WHERE users.user_id=company_users.C_C_OWNER 
AND company_users.C_C_USER_ID='22'
```